# How to fetch document directory from the document URI in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am having a list of URI's with different directories. Is it a way to fetch all the distinct directory from the URI's in MarkLogic ?

`xdmp:directory` is used for different purpose.

```
Example- 
let $uri := "/test/abc/somepath/abc.xml"
Output should be- "/test/abc/somepath/"
```

Any Suggestions ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a utility function that does this:

```
import module namespace util="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/utilities" at "/MarkLogic/utilities.xqy";
util:basepath("/test/abc/somepath/abc.xml")
```

It uses `fn:replace` plus a little logic around edge cases.

Comment: Secret undocumented function ;)

Comment: @mholstege-- Thank you. That helps :)

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in function for this, but you can parse out the directory value from a URI a couple different ways, depending on how strict you want to be.

```
fn:string-join(fn:tokenize('/test/abc/somepath/abc.xml', '/')[1 to last()-1], '/')||'/'
```

Or if you only want to match when the string leads with a `/`:

```
replace('/test/abc/somepath/abc.xml', '^((/[^/]+)*/)[^/]*$', '$1')
```

Comment: @wst-- Thank you so much. That makes sense to me. I used the inbuild `util:basepath` sugested by `mholstege`.